# How to remove the central white circle in a pie chart

Tags: android

I made a pie-chart in my Android app and I have a white cerce in the middlle I tried to remove it but I couldn't even the `piechart.setCentralCirculaire` doesn't work in my code. Is there any way that I can do that? Thanks.

[image: Chart]

```
pieChart=(PieChart)findViewById(R.id.Piechart);
pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

addDataSet();

private void addDataSet(){
    Log.d(TAG, "addDataSet: ");
    ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys=new ArrayList<>();
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(15.0f, "LOW"));
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(50.0f,"Normal"));
    yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(25.0f,"hyper"));
    PieDataSet pieDataSet= new PieDataSet(yEntrys,"Employee Global Activity");
    pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    ArrayList<Integer> colors =new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.RED);
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
    pieDataSet.setColors(colors);
    PieData pieData =new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
    pieChart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Show screenshot what are you getting?

Comment: there it is the sreenshot of the pie chart

Comment: What do you want to show in place of that white circle?

Comment: Show us your code where you create the pie-chart please.

Comment: You can edit you question and put your code in there.

Comment: yes sorry I have edited the comment : @HenriqueCésarMadeira, thanks

Comment: @HenriqueCésarMadeira  
I want the text and the data in the pie chart to be with the same color , I have used pieDataSet.setColor and piechart.setValuetextColro but it dosent work - do you know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 5):

```
piechart.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right this is a MPAndroidChart, so you uses.

```
piechart.setHoleRadius(0.0f);
```

Comment: yes its a MPAndroidChart .it works thank you but gave me transparent cercle is teher anyway to improve how it looks ?

Comment: Using piechart.setTransparentCircleColor(int color);

Comment: I want the text and the data in the pie chart to be with the same color , I have used pieDataSet.setColor and piechart.setValuetextColro but it dosent work -